# how to install scrapy on ubuntu?

Tags: python-2.7

I know that intall the scrapy should install the w3lib first,so I install the w3lib firstly,but when I import the scrapy in python ide,the program is crashed.
the error:

```
creating Twisted.egg-info

writing requirements to Twisted.egg-info\requires.txt

writing Twisted.egg-info\PKG-INFO

writing top-level names to Twisted.egg-info\top_level.txt

writing dependency_links to Twisted.egg-info\dependency_links.txt

writing manifest file 'Twisted.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'

warning: manifest_maker: standard file '-c' not found



reading manifest file 'Twisted.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'

writing manifest file 'Twisted.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'

copying twisted\internet\_sigchld.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\twisted\internet

creating build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\twisted\internet\iocpreactor\iocpsupport

copying twisted\internet/iocpreactor/iocpsupport\iocpsupport.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\twisted\internet/iocpreactor/i
ocpsupport

copying twisted\internet/iocpreactor/iocpsupport\winsock_pointers.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\twisted\internet/iocpreac
tor/iocpsupport

copying twisted\python\_epoll.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\twisted\python

copying twisted\python\_initgroups.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\twisted\python

copying twisted\python\sendmsg.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\twisted\python

copying twisted\runner\portmap.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\twisted\runner

copying twisted\test\raiser.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\twisted\test

running build_ext
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Make sure you had installed the Twisted, pyOpenSSL and pycrypto.
These are my steps to install scrapy on ubuntu.
1.install gcc and lxml:

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev
sudo apt-get install libevent-dev
sudo apt-get install libxml2 libxml2-dev
apt-get install libxml2-dev libxslt-dev
apt-get install python-lxml
```

2.install twisted:

```
sudo apt-get install python-twisted python-libxml2 python-simplejson

sudo apt-get install build-essential libssl-dev libffi-dev python-dev
```

3.install pyOpenSSL:

```
wget http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/pyOpenSSL/pyOpenSSL-0.13.tar.gz
tar -zxvf pyOpenSSL-0.13.tar.gz
cd pyOpenSSL-0.13
sudo python setup.py install
```

4.install pycrypto

```
wget http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/pycrypto/pycrypto-2.5.tar.gz
tar -zxvf pycrypto-2.5.tar.gz
cd pycrypto-2.5
sudo python setup.py install
```

5.install easy_install:(if you don't have easy_install)

```
wget http://peak.telecommunity.com/dist/ez_setup.py
python ez_setup.py
```

6.install w3lib

```
sudo easy_install -U w3lib
```

7.install scrapy

```
sudo easy_install Scrapy
```

If you wanna know much,please goto my blog.

Comment: I install the lxml failed when I run the command
apt-get install python-lxml

Comment: oh,my god,I forget that you should use the sudo,for example:sudo apt-get install python-lxml.

Answer (score 13):

This is how I installed scrapy on ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python-pip build-essential python-dev libxslt-dev libxml2-dev   
sudo -H pip install Scrapy
scrapy version
```

The important thing that solved my issues was `sudo -H pip install Scrapy` specifically the `-H` flag.

I also exited out of the terminal and started a new terminal to ensure the all the environment variables were set correctly

Answer (score 0):

First install system dependencies
    `sudo apt-get install -y \
        python-dev python-pip python-setuptools \
        libffi-dev libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev \
        libtiff5-dev libjpeg62-turbo-dev zlib1g-dev libfreetype6-dev \
        liblcms2-dev libwebp-dev tcl8.5-dev tk8.5-dev python-tk`

Then add followings in your requirements.txt

```
lxml
pyOpenSSL
Scrapy
Pillow
```

And finally pip install -r requirements.txt

You can look around gist.github.com as well to resolve latest dependencies issues. I'm using docker to setup scrapy deps in a separate container.
I've created one for mine needs [here](https://gist.github.com/zubairalam/4540eb73b41b7df06089)