# Installation issue with scrapy on ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu-12.04, scrapy

i am a recent linux convert interested in using scrapy.

```
jeremy@jeremy-Lenovo-G580:~/Dropbox/projects/scrapy_stuff$ uname -a
Linux jeremy-Lenovo-G580 3.5.0-52-generic #79~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jul 4 21:03:49 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

for such purposes i installed python 2.7

```
$ python -V
Python 2.7.3
```

then installed pip (using sudo easy_install pip) then used that to install scrapy0.24 using

```
sudo pip install scrapy
```

scrapy was working for a while , i ran the tutorial at  http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html fine .  whenever scrapy ran there was a complaint about service_identity so i installed that  with pip install (don't have the output of that unless its in  a log somewhere).  for some reason (maybe the service_identity?), scrapy broke -

```
$ scrapy -V
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/scrapy", line 4, in <module>
    execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 122, in execute
    cmds = _get_commands_dict(settings, inproject)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 46, in _get_commands_dict
    cmds = _get_commands_from_module('scrapy.commands', inproject)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 29, in _get_commands_from_module
    for cmd in _iter_command_classes(module):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 20, in _iter_command_classes
    for module in walk_modules(module_name):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/utils/misc.py", line 68, in walk_modules
    submod = import_module(fullpath)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/commands/bench.py", line 3, in <module>
    from scrapy.tests.mockserver import MockServer
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/tests/mockserver.py", line 6, in <module>
    from twisted.internet import reactor, defer, ssl
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/ssl.py", line 223, in <module>
    from twisted.internet._sslverify import (
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/_sslverify.py", line 184, in <module>
    verifyHostname, VerificationError = _selectVerifyImplementation()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/_sslverify.py", line 159, in _selectVerifyImplementation
    from service_identity import VerificationError
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/service_identity/__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    from . import pyopenssl
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/service_identity/pyopenssl.py", line 12, in <module>
    from pyasn1_modules.rfc2459 import GeneralNames
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyasn1_modules/rfc2459.py", line 72, in <module>
    class AttributeValue(univ.Any): pass
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Any'
```

So from http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/ubuntu.html#topics-ubuntu I  tried first uninstalling (sudo pip uninstall scrapy) and then

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 627220E7
echo 'deb http://archive.scrapy.org/ubuntu scrapy main' | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/scrapy.list
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install scrapy-0.24
```

and also tried uninstalling/resintalling scrapy a few times with pip install/uninstall, also tried easy_install scrapy, then tried updating with

```
 sudo pip install -U scrapy
```

which seems to be synonymous with

```
sudo pip intall --upgrade scrapy
```

( while first trying to install i had found an old version of scrapy was running tho a newer version had been installed, and after its removal was the one and only time i got scrapy running,so i suspected maybe an update would fix things again)

```
$sudo pip install -U scrapy

Requirement already up-to-date: scrapy in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Requirement already up-to-date: Twisted>=10.0.0 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from scrapy)
Requirement already up-to-date: w3lib>=1.2 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from scrapy)
Requirement already up-to-date: queuelib in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from scrapy)
Downloading/unpacking lxml from https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/l/lxml/lxml-3.3.5.tar.gz#md5=88c75f4c73fc8f59c9ebb17495044f2f (from scrapy)
  Downloading lxml-3.3.5.tar.gz (3.5MB): 3.5MB downloaded
  Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip_build_root/lxml/setup.py) egg_info for package lxml
    /usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'bugtrack_url'
      warnings.warn(msg)
    Building lxml version 3.3.5.
    Building without Cython.
    ERROR: /bin/sh: 1: xslt-config: not found

    ** make sure the development packages of libxml2 and libxslt are installed **

    Using build configuration of libxslt

    warning: no previously-included files found matching '*.py'
Downloading/unpacking pyOpenSSL from https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/pyOpenSSL/pyOpenSSL-0.14.tar.gz#md5=8579ff3a1d858858acfba5f046a4ddf7 (from scrapy)
  Downloading pyOpenSSL-0.14.tar.gz (128kB): 128kB downloaded
  Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip_build_root/pyOpenSSL/setup.py) egg_info for package pyOpenSSL

    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
    no previously-included directories found matching 'doc/_build'
Requirement already up-to-date: cssselect>=0.9 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from scrapy)
Requirement already up-to-date: six>=1.5.2 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from scrapy)
Downloading/unpacking zope.interface>=3.6.0 from https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/z/zope.interface/zope.interface-4.1.1.tar.gz#md5=edcd5f719c5eb2e18894c4d06e29b6c6 (from Twisted>=10.0.0->scrapy)
  Downloading zope.interface-4.1.1.tar.gz (864kB): 864kB downloaded
  Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip_build_root/zope.interface/setup.py) egg_info for package zope.interface

    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.dll' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyo' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.so' found anywhere in distribution
Downloading/unpacking cryptography>=0.2.1 (from pyOpenSSL->scrapy)
  Downloading cryptography-0.5.1.tar.gz (319kB): 319kB downloaded
  Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip_build_root/cryptography/setup.py) egg_info for package cryptography

    Installed /tmp/pip_build_root/cryptography/cffi-0.8.6-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg
    Searching for pycparser
    Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/pycparser/
    Best match: pycparser 2.10
    Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/pycparser/pycparser-2.10.tar.gz#md5=d87aed98c8a9f386aa56d365fe4d515f
    Processing pycparser-2.10.tar.gz
    Running pycparser-2.10/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-LtjYh9/pycparser-2.10/egg-dist-tmp-1dc4kT
    zip_safe flag not set; analyzing archive contents...

    Installed /tmp/pip_build_root/cryptography/pycparser-2.10-py2.7.egg

    building '_Cryptography_cffi_684bb40axf342507b' extension
    gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c cryptography/hazmat/primitives/__pycache__/_Cryptography_cffi_684bb40axf342507b.c -o /tmp/pip_build_root/cryptography/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/__pycache__/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/__pycache__/_Cryptography_cffi_684bb40axf342507b.o
    gcc -pthread -shared -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro /tmp/pip_build_root/cryptography/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/__pycache__/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/__pycache__/_Cryptography_cffi_684bb40axf342507b.o -o /tmp/pip_build_root/cryptography/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/__pycache__/_Cryptography_cffi_684bb40axf342507b.so
    building '_Cryptography_cffi_8f86901cxc1767c5a' extension
    gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c cryptography/hazmat/primitives/__pycache__/_Cryptography_cffi_8f86901cxc1767c5a.c -o /tmp/pip_build_root/cryptography/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/__pycache__/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/__pycache__/_Cryptography_cffi_8f86901cxc1767c5a.o
    gcc -pthread -shared -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro /tmp/pip_build_root/cryptography/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/__pycache__/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/__pycache__/_Cryptography_cffi_8f86901cxc1767c5a.o -o /tmp/pip_build_root/cryptography/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/__pycache__/_Cryptography_cffi_8f86901cxc1767c5a.so
    building '_Cryptography_cffi_79a5b0a3x3a8a382' extension
    gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c cryptography/hazmat/bindings/__pycache__/_Cryptography_cffi_79a5b0a3x3a8a382.c -o /tmp/pip_build_root/cryptography/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/__pycache__/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/__pycache__/_Cryptography_cffi_79a5b0a3x3a8a382.o
    gcc -pthread -shared -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro /tmp/pip_build_root/cryptography/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/__pycache__/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/__pycache__/_Cryptography_cffi_79a5b0a3x3a8a382.o -lcrypto -lssl -o /tmp/pip_build_root/cryptography/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/__pycache__/_Cryptography_cffi_79a5b0a3x3a8a382.so
    no previously-included directories found matching 'docs/_build'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*' found under directory 'vectors'
Downloading/unpacking setuptools from https://pypi.python.org/packages/3.4/s/setuptools/setuptools-5.4.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl#md5=5b7b07029ad2285d1cbf809a8ceaea08 (from zope.interface>=3.6.0->Twisted>=10.0.0->scrapy)
  Downloading setuptools-5.4.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (528kB): 528kB downloaded
Downloading/unpacking cffi>=0.8 (from cryptography>=0.2.1->pyOpenSSL->scrapy)
  Downloading cffi-0.8.6.tar.gz (196kB): 196kB downloaded
  Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip_build_root/cffi/setup.py) egg_info for package cffi

Downloading/unpacking pycparser (from cffi>=0.8->cryptography>=0.2.1->pyOpenSSL->scrapy)
  Downloading pycparser-2.10.tar.gz (206kB): 206kB downloaded
  Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip_build_root/pycparser/setup.py) egg_info for package pycparser

Installing collected packages: lxml, pyOpenSSL, zope.interface, cryptography, setuptools, cffi, pycparser
  Found existing installation: lxml 2.3.2
    Uninstalling lxml:
      Successfully uninstalled lxml
  Running setup.py install for lxml
    /usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'bugtrack_url'
      warnings.warn(msg)
    Building lxml version 3.3.5.
    Building without Cython.
    ERROR: /bin/sh: 1: xslt-config: not found

    ** make sure the development packages of libxml2 and libxslt are installed **

    Using build configuration of libxslt
    building 'lxml.etree' extension
    gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/tmp/pip_build_root/lxml/src/lxml/includes -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c src/lxml/lxml.etree.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/lxml/lxml.etree.o -w
    In file included from src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:346:0:
    /tmp/pip_build_root/lxml/src/lxml/includes/etree_defs.h:9:31: fatal error: libxml/xmlversion.h: No such file or directory
    compilation terminated.
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
    Complete output from command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip_build_root/lxml/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-Iog1QC-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    /usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'bugtrack_url'

  warnings.warn(msg)

Building lxml version 3.3.5.

Building without Cython.

ERROR: /bin/sh: 1: xslt-config: not found



** make sure the development packages of libxml2 and libxslt are installed **



Using build configuration of libxslt

running install

running build

running build_py

creating build

creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7

creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml

copying src/lxml/builder.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml

copying src/lxml/sax.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml

copying src/lxml/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml

copying src/lxml/pyclasslookup.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml

copying src/lxml/ElementInclude.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml

copying src/lxml/_elementpath.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml

copying src/lxml/cssselect.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml

copying src/lxml/doctestcompare.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml

copying src/lxml/usedoctest.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml

creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/includes

copying src/lxml/includes/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/includes

creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/html

copying src/lxml/html/html5parser.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/html

copying src/lxml/html/_diffcommand.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/html

copying src/lxml/html/builder.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/html

copying src/lxml/html/defs.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/html

copying src/lxml/html/clean.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/html

copying src/lxml/html/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/html

copying src/lxml/html/ElementSoup.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/html

copying src/lxml/html/diff.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/html

copying src/lxml/html/_setmixin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/html

copying src/lxml/html/soupparser.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/html

copying src/lxml/html/formfill.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/html

copying src/lxml/html/_html5builder.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/html

copying src/lxml/html/usedoctest.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/html

creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/isoschematron

copying src/lxml/isoschematron/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/isoschematron

copying src/lxml/lxml.etree.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml

copying src/lxml/lxml.etree_api.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml

copying src/lxml/includes/xpath.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/includes

copying src/lxml/includes/relaxng.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/includes

copying src/lxml/includes/xmlparser.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/includes

copying src/lxml/includes/xinclude.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/includes

copying src/lxml/includes/xslt.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/includes

copying src/lxml/includes/c14n.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/includes

copying src/lxml/includes/dtdvalid.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/includes

copying src/lxml/includes/schematron.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/includes

copying src/lxml/includes/htmlparser.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/includes

copying src/lxml/includes/config.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/includes

copying src/lxml/includes/xmlerror.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/includes

copying src/lxml/includes/uri.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/includes

copying src/lxml/includes/etreepublic.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/includes

copying src/lxml/includes/tree.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/includes

copying src/lxml/includes/xmlschema.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/includes

copying src/lxml/includes/etree_defs.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/includes

copying src/lxml/includes/lxml-version.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/includes

creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/isoschematron/resources

creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/isoschematron/resources/rng

copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/rng/iso-schematron.rng -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/isoschematron/resources/rng

creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl

copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/RNG2Schtrn.xsl -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl

copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/XSD2Schtrn.xsl -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl

creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1

copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/iso_dsdl_include.xsl -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1

copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/iso_svrl_for_xslt1.xsl -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1

copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/iso_abstract_expand.xsl -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1

copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/iso_schematron_skeleton_for_xslt1.xsl -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1

copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/iso_schematron_message.xsl -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1

copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/readme.txt -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1

running build_ext

building 'lxml.etree' extension

creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7

creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src

creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/lxml

gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/tmp/pip_build_root/lxml/src/lxml/includes -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c src/lxml/lxml.etree.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/lxml/lxml.etree.o -w

In file included from src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:346:0:

/tmp/pip_build_root/lxml/src/lxml/includes/etree_defs.h:9:31: fatal error: libxml/xmlversion.h: No such file or directory

compilation terminated.

error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
  Rolling back uninstall of lxml
Cleaning up...
Command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip_build_root/lxml/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-Iog1QC-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip_build_root/lxml
Storing debug log for failure in /home/jeremy/.pip/pip.log
```

One wierd thing (at i think its wierd) i just noticed , pip doesn't run at all but sudo pip does

```
jeremy@jeremy-Lenovo-G580:~/Dropbox/projects/scrapy_stuff$ pip install scrapy
bash: /usr/bin/pip: No such file or directory
jeremy@jeremy-Lenovo-G580:~/Dropbox/projects/scrapy_stuff$ sudo pip install scrapy
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): scrapy in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): Twisted>=10.0.0 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from scrapy)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): w3lib>=1.2 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from scrapy)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): queuelib in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from scrapy)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): lxml in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from scrapy)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pyOpenSSL in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from scrapy)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): cssselect>=0.9 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from scrapy)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): six>=1.5.2 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from scrapy)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): zope.interface>=3.6.0 in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from Twisted>=10.0.0->scrapy)
Cleaning up...
```

so, I'll try to install development packages of libxml2 and libxslt but am not optimistic at this point - i'm rather stuck down  a rabbit hole and am unclear as to what broke the working scrapy in the first place...any help appreciated, my brown hair is turning grey, the grey is turning white, and the white is combusting.

maybe i should just try running python and scrapy on the windows virtualbox i  set up (that went quite  easy btw) but it sort of defeats the purpose of switching to linux (which was that i'd be closer to the source of a lot of the projects i find interesting, and the open aspect)

ok so i just tried

```
sudo apt-get install libxml2-dev
sudo apt-get install libxslt1-dev 
sudo apt-get install python2.7-dev
```

but scrapy still dying horribly with attributeerror : module object has no attribute 'any'

Comment: Have you tried using sudo apt-get install python-scrapy ?

Comment: I purposely haven't yet due to the warning here [http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/install].      _Ubuntu 9.10 or above

Don’t use the python-scrapy package provided by Ubuntu, they are typically too old and slow to catch up with latest Scrapy._

Comment: Yes, but since pip and easy_install aren't working for you, this seems to be a plausible option. Also, sudo apt-get install python-scrapy will install all the missing dependencies. After that, you can again try to upgrade you Scrapy installation using pip.

Comment: tried it, no dice.  same error (attributeError) after sudo apt-get install python-scrapy, same error after sudo pip install scrapy, same error after sudo pip install --upgrade scrapy...sigh....

Comment: Hard luck dude. Try submitting a ticket on scrapy github page.

Answer (score 1):

A reinstall of ubuntu took care of it, perhaps drastic but effective. I installed ubuntu14LTS instead of the 12LTS I had started with. Only hiccup was after

```
$sudo apt-get install python-pip
$sudo pip install scrapy
...
twisted/runner/portmap.c:10:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
```

but

```
 sudo apt-get install build-essential python-dev
```

took care of it. Hopefully this time scrapy will work for more than an hour.  2 days well spent?

Comment: update - scrapy -V would run but trying the tutorial gave this error                                                                                                                                       'File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/utils/misc.py", line 42, in load_object raise ImportError("Error loading object '%s': %s" % (path, e)) ImportError: Error loading object "scrapy.telnet.TelnetConsole": No module named conch'                   which was solved by 'sudo apt-get install python-twisted'  - i guess the pip install is not checking dependencies entirely correctly

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue and have not found a solution as yet. I do however don't think that installing a new OS should be the answer

Comment: you're surely right, at the time i had just installed ubuntu12 and so upgrading to 14.04 didn't faze me.  to get help you;d prob have to get specific on os and python/scrapy versions

Comment: I've since found a solution and documented it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22556965/how-to-install-scrapy-on-ubuntu/35608590#35608590 
Just in case someone else is stuck

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this issue on Ubuntu 14.04. I made certain that all the requirements were installed for *service_identity 16.0.0*; listed [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/service_identity). I was missing *pyasn1*, *pyasn1-modules* (installed via pip), but had overlooked *attrs*. Removing *service_identity* and reinstalling it picked that package up:

```
yes | pip uninstall service_identity; pip install service_identity
```

However, using pip's upgrade functionality with service_identity did not resolve the issue.